# How can I pass a Swift array as an argument to a thread?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, oop, swift

I'm trying to spawn a new thread to do some background processing, based on a String that I've broken down into an array of characters. Here's what my code looks like:

```
   var testString : String = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   var testStringArray : Array<Character> = []

   for character in testString
   {
       if(!(self.isCharacterStrippable(character)))
       {
           testStringArray.append(character)
       }
   }

   NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector("fillKeysFromArray:", toTarget: self, withObject: testStringArray)
```

I get a compiler error telling me that "Array does not conform to protocol AnyObject".

Short of writing an object wrapper for my array, or setting it as an instance variable (both of which seem like overkill), is there any way I can get this array passed through to the new thread?

Comment: use GCD dispatch_async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) is going to be much easier in the long run.  You can run your function on a background thread with something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    [weak self] in // This is so that we don't create a reference cycle
    self?.fillKeysFromArray(testStringArray);
    return
}
```

You can read up on Grand Central Dispatch and all the nice things it provides when it comes to threading and concurrency in Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that `detachNewThreadSelector` can only accept a `NSMutableArray` for the `withObject` parameter. If you make `testStringArray` a variable of type `NSMutableArray` you can get rid of the compiler error message.

Having said that, you should seriously consider the advices from Bryan Chen and Mike S to switch to GCD.

Comment: I tried that...but the elements of an NSMutableArray have to be objects, and the Swift type Character isn't an object. So that just means I'd need an object wrapper for each Character instead of one for the Array.